# Why does $q.when followed by $q.reject in Angular.js result in success?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

In Angular.js when using $q, why doesn't this code:

```
 $q.when("test")
   .then($q.reject("error"))
   .then(
     function(v) {
       $scope.result = "Success: " + v;
     },
     function(e) {
       $scope.result = "Failure: " + e;
     }
   )
```

call the error callback?

In a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c9tv6kz7/1/

Comment: You want `$q.when("error").then($q.reject)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more simple answer is that:

`$q.reject("error")`

creates a new promise object which is invoked by your `$q.when().then()`.

This will really not do what you think. `$q.reject("error")` returns an object with a `then` function on it.

Look at the section **Methods** in the [docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.10/docs/api/ng/service/$q):

```
promiseB = promiseA.then(function(result) {
  // success: do something and resolve promiseB
  //          with the old or a new result
  return result;
}, function(reason) {
  // error: handle the error if possible and
  //        resolve promiseB with newPromiseOrValue,
  //        otherwise forward the rejection to promiseB
  if (canHandle(reason)) {
   // handle the error and recover
   return newPromiseOrValue;
  }
  return $q.reject(reason);
});
```

Do you see how they are doing `then(function () { return $q.reject(reason); })` which is vastly different from your original.

See new [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/12q6yh4c/)

Answer (score 3):

[Per the doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

> then(successCallback, errorCallback, notifyCallback) – regardless of
>   when the promise was or will be resolved or rejected, then calls one
>   of the success or error callbacks asynchronously as soon as the result
>   is available. The callbacks are called with a single argument: the
>   result or rejection reason. Additionally, the notify callback may be
>   called zero or more times to provide a progress indication, before the
>   promise is resolved or rejected.
>
> This method returns a new promise which is resolved or rejected via
>   the return value of the successCallback, errorCallback (unless that
>   value is a promise, in which case it is resolved with the value which
>   is resolved in that promise using promise chaining). It also notifies
>   via the return value of the notifyCallback method. The promise cannot
>   be resolved or rejected from the notifyCallback method.

The line we really care about is

> This method returns a new promise which is resolved or rejected via
>   the return value of the successCallback, errorCallback

Each time you call `then` on `$q.when` you are creating a new promise. Even though the first promise was rejected the second one was not. The second wasn't rejected because the return value of your successCallback and errorCallback did not reject it.

Comment: Not sure I follow. What I expect to happen is: 1) 'when' creates a promise that immediately resolves with success 2) 'reject' creates a promise that immediately resolves (rejects) with failure 3) 'then' creates a promise that sequentially resolves the first one, then the second one 4) if either of the two fails, 'then' should resolve with an error.

Comment: The misunderstanding is you are expecting your promises to be interconnected. The way you have it written,that  is not the case. Each of your promises are independent of the previous. So if one fails the other will not.

Answer (score 0):

When I do it like this, I resolve an error:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$q', function($scope, $q) {
  $q.when("test")
    $q.reject('Failed!')
    .then(
      function(v) {
        $scope.result = "Success: " + v;
      },
      function(e) {
        $scope.result = "Failure: " + e;
      }
    )
}]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/emporio/67db45f9/3/

If I remove `$q.reject('Failed!')`, it will resolve to .then().

Comment: You get the error because $q.reject('failed!') is a failed promise. Your scenario is not OP's. Is scenario is, he is wrapping a failed promise within a promise.

Comment: OP's? What does that mean?